# A general Addin for office solution

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, shared-addin

Is there a possibility of having a general addin for Microsoft office and the same addin is visible in all Office solutions such as EXCEL, WORD, POWERPOINT etc. We can create individual addins for these applications separately but having a common solution would serve my purpose e.g. if I need to tag  some information to all of my documents to be printed.

Any sort of information is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a possibility of having a general addin for Microsoft office and the same addin is visible in all Office solutions such as EXCEL, WORD, POWERPOINT etc.

**Yes**

There are two types of Add-In

- VSTO Add-Ins *(I will use `VAI` for short in describing them below)*
- Shared Add-Ins *(I will use `SAI` for short in describing them below)*

`VAI` are application-specific viz, MS Excel, MS Word etc. On the other hand `SAI` can be written for more than one application i.e can be shared between MS Excel, MS Word etc. Also I am sure that you are aware that `VAI` has only two main methods. One for `startup` and the other for `shutdown`. However `SAI` has to implement different methods for `connection`, `unconnecting`, `startup` and `shutdown`.

Another thing that is important to note is that since `VAI` is application specific there is not too much of code involved as compared to `SAI`. The reason being `SAI` work across different applications and hence you need to extra code to distinguish which application is currently calling your Add-in.

I prefer `VAI` because it lets me use additional programming "shortcuts" and useful objects not available in a Shared Add-in. Not that these are cannot be used in `SAI` but then you will have to specifically create them. An unnecessary added work if I may say so.

And the last that I can think of is the deployment. They both have a different deployment method.

Hope this clears the concept of a `VAI` and `SAI`

Comment: is there any blog written on this sort of development?

Comment: @Shaktisaxena: Not that I am aware of :) Did you try searching google?

Comment: @Shaktisaxena: Then maybe one day I will :D